# Spring rest docs not processing html tags

Tags: java, unit-testing, documentation, spring-restdocs

Using rest docs, I define the following parameter:

```
RequestPartsSnippet parts = requestParts(
            partWithName("name").description("The name of the service. Example: <pre> some json </pre>")
 );
```

Then I call the service in that way in my tests:

```
    Response response = target
       .register(documentationConfiguration(doc))
       .register(document("department-200", 
               preprocessRequest(removeUserAgent, Preprocessors.prettyPrint()),
               preprocessResponse(Preprocessors.prettyPrint()),
               requestParameters(desc),
               parts))
       .request()
       .header("Authorization", admin)
       .post(Entity.entity(multi, multi.getMediaType()));
```

Here's the related adoc file line:

```
.request-fields
include::{snippets}/department-200/request-parts.adoc[]
```

I would expect the json in the parameter description to be formatted with the tag pre. However the tag is converted into its html symbol equivalent.

What I need to change to have the json correctly formatted into my browser?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Asciidoc formatting in the description rather than HTML. For example, you could surround the JSON with single back ticks.